# Automatic power selection circuit design and part selection

Tags: power, mosfet, battery-charging, schottky

I am working on a project that has LIPO battery and a USB as a power inputs. The system should use the battery but if the USB cable is plugged it has to use that as a power source instead of the battery.

[image]

The design is mostly based on Adafruit ESP32 feather https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/041/630/original/feather_schem.png?1494449413. If I understand it correctly the MOSFET is turned off if V_USB is < than V_BATT.

I plan to have this board assembled by JLC PCB and both the MOSFETs and the Schottky diode are extended parts. I want to replace them by basic parts to make it cheaper so I'm looking for alternative parts, Are B5819W and AO3400A adequate replacements in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AO3400A](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AO3400A.pdf) is a N-channel MOSFET while the [DMG3415U](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds31735.pdf) shown in the diagram is a P-channel device. So, no, the AO3400A is not suitable as a substitute.

I don't see any problem with using the [B5819W](http://www.smc-diodes.com/propdf/B5817W-B5819W%20N1752%20REV.-.pdf) diode as a substitute. Given it's function in the circuit, it should do fine.

The [AO3401A](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AO3401A.pdf) given in the comments is indeed a P-channel device and looks like it is suitable. It has a bit higher ON resistance at around 5Vgs, so it'll dissipate a bit more power but nothing significant.

Comment: You are right, AO3401A